# How does the route decorator used in Flask work

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm familiar with the basics of Python's decorators. However I don't understand how this specific decorator, as used for Flask routes, works.

Here is a code snippet from the Flask website:

```
from flask import Flask, escape, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    name = request.args.get("name", "World")
    return f'Hello, {escape(name)}!'
```

`.route('/')` is the part which confuses me. The way I've seen decorators being used is that the decorator annoation is usually a function, which takes one argument, which is the decorated function itself, which can then be executed inside the decorator. But this seems to be different here.

Thank you.

Update: Thanks for the hint about `self` in my second code snippet. Being new to Python I totally forgot that `something`'s first argument has to be `self`. At second glance, I don't think that the example helps to clarify the question and have therefore removed it.

Comment: This might help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-with-parameters-in-python/

Comment: The first argument should be your regular `self`, not `arg1`. Just because an object is used as decorator Python's language doesn't change suddenly.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt if you had just written the first sentence, I wouldn't think you were being condescending.

Comment: I'm sorry if you perceived it as that. What I really wanted to tell you was that "all regular rules apply" and that this is not something special.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a couple misconceptions that we can hopefully clear up. Firstly, a decorator is just a term (*and some language "sugar", the `@decorator` syntax*) for a callable that accepts a callable and returns another callable. This callable can be a function (*e.g., `def foo(func)`*) or a method (*e.g., `obj.method(func)`*) -- it just needs to be something that accepts a callable and returns one.

In the case of Flask's `@app.route` decorator, you're passing your `hello` function to an object's (*the `flask.Flask` object I believe*) `route` method. In turn it adds your function and its associated configuration to its own "memory" for routing once the Flask application is told to begin serving requests.

Secondly, your example has `def something(arg1, arg2):` -- the first argument passed to an object's method when called is the object instance, usually called `self`

The [Primer on Python Decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) article might be a good place to get started to read up on how/why they work the way they do.

Answer (score 1):

A decorator is simply a function that accepts a function as a parameter and returns another function. A decorator that accepts arguments (like flask's `route` decorator) must return a function that can be used as a simple decorator.

For example, we could write that `route` decorator like this:

```
routes = {}


def route(path):
    def inner(func):
        global routes
        routes[path] = func
        return func

    return inner
```

Calling `route('/')` returns a function that takes a function as an argument, which updates the global `routes` variable using the value of `path` passed to the outer function and the `func` value received by the inner function.

If we use that on a couple of functions:

```
@route('/')
def func1():
    ...

@route('/example')
def func2():
    ...
```

Then we can inspect the `routes` variable and see that it now maps paths to the appropriate functions. Running:

```
print(routes)
```

Produces something like:

```
{'/': <function func1 at 0x7f0c4aeac050>, '/example': <function func2 at 0x7f0c4aeb1e60>}
```